# How to display multiple related entries automatically in Expression Engine?

Tags: php, expressionengine

What is the best way to display multiple related entries in EE automatically?. I am working on the newspaper website. There are hundreds of  news articles that are related with each other.It is very hard to manually relate one article with another one.Is there a plugin  that will automatically read the content of the page and return the possible related articles.Please suggest the best solution to my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have used [this module](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/tag) a couple of times, now - it uses tag words to create relationships between entries.

Comment: Thank for reply I tried that but I am afraid that my client will  mistype on tag words and possibility of similar or duplicate values.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking to have your entries *automagically* related, or will you be relating them manually?

If you'll be curating the relationships yourself, look no further than [Playa](http://pixelandtonic.com/playa) by Pixel and Tonic — its feature set and ease of use is unmatched.

Depending on the taxonomy of your site, you could use ExpressionEngine's built-in [Entry Categories](http://expressionengine.com/user_guide/modules/channel/channel_entries.html#categories) or the excellent third-party [Solspace Tag Module](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/tag) as a way to automatically relate entries to one another.

Furthermore, to relate entries using the *text contained in your articles*, you could use the [Search Parameter](http://expressionengine.com/user_guide/modules/channel/channel_entries.html#search-field-name) to build the list of related articles, based on the content within one or more of the entry's custom fields.

For instance, let's say you had a custom field that contained a list of keywords. You could use the **channel entry search parameter** to build a list of entries containing one or more of those keywords:

```
{exp:channel:entries dynamic="off" search:keywords="beer|lager"}
    {title}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

You'd need to use an early parsed variable such as [Low Variables](http://gotolow.com/addons/low-variables) to make the static `"search:"` text in your templates dynamic.

*On high traffic sites there could be serious performance considerations with this approach, so you might consider looking for a more robust implementation or building a custom add-on to suit your needs.*

Like all things built with ExpressionEngine, there are several different ways to accomplish a single goal, so keep your mind open and choose the best solution for your needs.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I want my article to be related automatically based on the content of the article body. I tried with Playa, but in Playa you have to select the article that you want to relate with. This is  tedious process esp when you have hundred of article that you are migrating from the old system. With the Tag module I am afraid  that authors may misspell the words or they may use different words to describe the content of the article. I need something that will automatically ready the body filed in my article channel and create the related entries on the fly.

Comment: I added another method to my answer that may aide in your situation, using the channel entry search parameter.

Comment: Thanks again for your reply.I understand the concept that you are providing me. Can I use the same concept here lets say I have a channel name article and it has custom fields article_body. There are more than 1000 articles in the database already.When I click the link for article A I want to display all the related Article  for that article A, but based on the matching content from article_body custom field. The article_body could have easily 3000 words in it. so how can I parse the very common words like a,an,the,etc and only pick the matching words and display my related articles.

Answer (score 0):

Could you not just grab the current category(ies) and pull a selection of related articles that way? Then you could sort them by date or popularity.